# Keep open fold open on `o`

Tags: insert-mode, normal-mode, folding

I have a file with `foldmethod=indent`. I have the folds automatically open when I enter them, and close when I leave them. When I sit in Normal mode on the bottom line of a fold and press `o`, the fold closes and I can't see what is in it.

I want Vim to understand that when I'm in a fold and type a command that leaves the fold but enters Insert mode, I want that fold to stay open.

Comment: I assume you're using `:set foldclose=all`, correct? I don't think there's a setting that will prevent the fold from closing while you append a new line with `o` at the end of a fold when that setting is enabled though...

Comment: I am indeed using `:set foldclose=all`. How about using `autocmd InsertEnter ...`? That's what I tried before, although I am not good enough at Vimscript to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the `indent` fold method has some flaws, and this is one of them. My solution might not be the best, but here it is:

I created my own fold implementation in my vimrc:

```
function! FoldLevel(lnum)
    return ( max([
        \     indent(prevnonblank(a:lnum)),
        \     indent(nextnonblank(a:lnum))
        \ ]) / getbufvar('.', '&tabstop', 1) )
endfunction


set foldmethod=expr
set foldexpr=FoldLevel(v:lnum)
```

You just need to put that in your `.vimrc`, and you should be good to go!